# Dict comprehensions for creating a new dict from an old dict using iteritems vs dictionary lookup

Tags: python, dictionary

I was creating a new dict from an old dict, where I only wanted to append a letter to the name of the key, when I had this thought:

Which of these two dict comprehensions are more efficient (or, more Pythonic?)

```
{k: v for k, v in other_dict.iteritems()}
```

or

```
{k: other_dict[k] for k in other_dict}
```

I would normally think to go with the first one, but absentmindedly typed in the second one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test it. But in practice, except possibly for very small dictionaries, the `iteritems` will work faster, simply because it avoids an unnecessary lookup.

`iteritems` is definitely better style. Of course, if the goal is just to make a copy (like your example), then the best style (and performance) is found with just:

```
other_dict.copy()
```